# Неправильно работает php проверка на друзья

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте. Есть код, проверки находится ли данный пользователь у тебя в друзьях или нет, было ли отправлено ему приглашение и т.д. Собственно, почему то, результат отображает некорректно.
Собственно сам код:

```
if($profile != $_SESSION['user_id']) {
   $query66 = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM friends_temp WHERE loginfrom='{$_SESSION['user_id']}' and tofriend='{$profile}'");
   if(!$query66){
      $query4 = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT id_acc,id_friend FROM friends WHERE id_acc='{$_SESSION['user_id']}' and id_friend='{$profile}'");
      while ($row4 = mysqli_fetch_array($query4)){
         $zapi = $row4['id_friend'];
         if(!$zapi){
            echo"<li class='pr_ui_s'><a href='#' class='pr_ui_a'><span>Добавить в други</span></a></li>";
         }else{
            echo"<li class='pr_ui_s'><a href='#' class='pr_ui_a'><span>Вы уже дружите</span></a></li>";
         }
      }
   }else{
      echo"<li class='pr_ui_s'><a href='#' class='pr_ui_a'><span>Запрос отправлен</span></a></li>";
   }
}
```

`$link` - собственно подключение к базе
`$_SESSION['user_id']` - берется из сессии
`$profile` - id пользователя на странице которого я сейчас нахожусь

Весь вечер ломаю голову, но все время результатом выводит, что запрос отправлен. Даже уже проверил, не является ли это проблема связанная с **sql**. Но нет, это проблема в коде. 
Кто может поправить или найти ошибку - помогите. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: А какая ошибка? Опишите подробнее. Покажите связь между таблицами. Дополните вопрос.

Comment: Выводится строка, что запрос отправлен. Хотя по факту ничего такого. Проверял на разных статусах. (если мы уже друзья, если только отправлен запрос, если мы еще не друзья и запрос не отправлен)

Может логика нарушена? хотя я вроде бы проверял.

Comment: Попробуйте вместо `if(!$query66)` использовать `if(!mysqli_num_rows($query66))`

Comment: В коде есть потенциально проблемные места. 1) `$profile != $_SESSION['user_id']` - приведение типов, может пропускать непонятные значения. 2) Выведите значение строк запросов и запустите их напрямую на базе(Может запрос неправильно собирает). 3) `var_dump` или `xdebug` вам в помощь.

Comment: Разделяйте презентацию от бизнес логики. SQL, PHP, HTML в одном файле, это не хорошо.

Comment: E_p       $profile != $_SESSION['user_id'] - не понимаю с чем тут возник у вас вопрос. id сравнивается c id...

@P. Fateev сработало только для записей, кто уже является другом и кому отправлен запрос. А вот кто не в друзьях и кому не отправлен запрос нет.
Как я понимаю, я не правильно проверяю наличие или пустоту значения ?
Потому как вывод значений после выборки ничего не показывает,(только у тех записей, где все срабатывает нормально)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  if ($profile != $_SESSION['user_id']) {
     $query66 = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT 1 FROM friends_temp WHERE loginfrom='{$_SESSION['user_id']}' AND tofriend='{$profile}'");
     if ($query66) {
        if (mysqli_num_rows($query66)) {
           echo "<li class='pr_ui_s'><a href='#' class='pr_ui_a'><span>Запрос отправлен</span></a></li>";
        } else {
           $query4 = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT 1 FROM friends WHERE id_acc='{$_SESSION['user_id']}' AND id_friend='{$profile}'");
           if ($query4) {
              if (mysqli_num_rows($query4)) {
                 echo "<li class='pr_ui_s'><a href='#' class='pr_ui_a'><span>Вы уже дружите</span></a></li>";
              } else {
                 echo "<li class='pr_ui_s'><a href='#' class='pr_ui_a'><span>Добавить в други</span></a></li>";
              }
           }
        }
     }   
  }
```

Comment: Спасибо. Работает. Обязательно разберусь в вашем коде.